# JSON transformation with JOLT library

Tags: jolt

This is my input JSON :

```json
{
    "clause": {
        "typeClause": "CLAUSE_TYPE",
        "codeClause": "CL03"
    }
}
```

Why it works:

```json
[
    {
        "operation": "com.kapia.kaway.penelop.jolt.Transco",
        "spec": {
            "clause": {
                "texte": "=stubToGetSecondParameter('CL03','lorem ipsum')"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "clause": {
                "typeClause": {
                    "CLAUSE_TYPE": {
                        "@(2,texte)": "clause.texte"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Output :

```json
{
    "clause": {
        "texte": "lorem ipsum"
    }
}
```

But not this:

```json
[
    {
        "operation": "com.kapia.kaway.penelop.jolt.Transco",
        "spec": {
            "clause": {
                "typeClause": {
                    "CLAUSE_TYPE": {
                        "texte": "=stubToGetSecondParameter('CL03','lorem ipsum')"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "clause": {
                "typeClause": {
                    "CLAUSE_TYPE": {
                        "@(0,texte)": "clause.texte"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

If typeClause = "CLAUSE_TYPE" then I'd like to retrieve the value corresponding to the "codeClause" by calling a java class.

The objective is :

1. In the first jolt operation, call a Java method based on the value of a json input property (if-else structure) and store the java method's return value in a variable.
2. In the next jolt operation, use the same if-else structure and define the json path of the response with the value of the variable

Comment: Hi gbouget. Why don't you try `"@2,texte"` within **shift** opr. as well instead of the current `"@0,texte"` ?

Comment: hello Barbaros, yes, now I understand better the sequence of operations jolt. Thank you